# HikariCP not recovering after AWS RDS Postgress DB failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, hikaricp

Environment:

Hikari CP Version: 3.5.4
JDK Version: Zulu64-11.0.9
Database: AWS RDS - Postgres
Spring Boot Version: 2.4.13

We have a Spring Boot application with AWS RDS Postgres as the backend. When the Postgres database fails over due to a hardware issue or is restarted, the Spring Boot application is unable to connect to the failover database, which becomes available within one minute.

If we restart the Spring Boot app, it recovers. Additionally, if we wait for an hour, it recovers automatically.

any ideas on how to resolve this issue where the Hikari connection pool is unable to recover?